# Extending Wordpress search

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I have a small problem in a wordpress project that I have worked in the past, the solution that I applied there for a custom plugin was to create a couple of tables for some projects that the admin has the ability to add. My mistake was to not make taxonomies and register them in wordpress. Now those projects must appear in the search results. My question is: How/where can I write some code to include a custom table in the search ( where 'q' LIKE %title% ) to apply for the internal search and let wordpress calculate the pagination and show the results? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress had capability to use native mysql query. So you just use the native query to search

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT *
    FROM posts
    WHERE post_title LIKE %title% 
    ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
foreach ($pageposts as $post):
  echo $post->post_title;
endforeach;
```

About paging, count the row and do paging manually. I think you can do that.

Comment: Hello @evilkiro - Thank you for the interest and response, I know that I can to the native mysql query, but I don`t know how to push the results in the wordpress search result object. Currently I am on query.php file in wp-includes in the get_posts() function and trying to add there somehow my results treated as post ( without luck for the moment ).